# How can I reduce latency while tethering?

Tags: motorola-droid, hardware, tethering, internet, wi-fi

When tethering with PDAnet (the free version), using a stock moto-Droid 1 on Verizon, I am getting between 1k-3k ms latency on World of Warcraft. I would like to know what is the likeliest culprit, and am wondering what steps (and how) I can take to reduce the latency.

Some ideas:

- Change tethering app? (Note, I have a limited use and purchasing a $30 app for tethering isn't really an option)
- Root/ROM and change from stock? (running 2.2.1: FRG83D)
- Get a latency targeting app for my phone/laptop?

Comment: Your latency is most likely caused by your phone's signal/carrier. I'm doubtful that changing to a different tethering app would help.

Comment: I agree with Bryan.  Cell networks have much more delay than cable internet.

Comment: @Bry I was afraid of that. I would add an option above for changing carriers, but there are way too many localized variables for any kind of answer to help. Maybe someone can make some incremental recommendations.

Comment: I wouldn't ever use something as latency-sensitive and data intensive as WoW over tethered 3G.

Comment: @Al Ev oh it's good times. the character does something that normally take 2.5 seconds, and the action goes on for 15. good times.

Comment: Agreed with @al. I sometimes have difficult just browsing websites with tethering due to latency, even on 3g.  It works, sure, but it isn't the fastest way.

Comment: It will be the same no matter which carrier you use.  They're just not built for low-latency response.

Comment: Well, whoever want to write to most comprehensive answer on *why* this problem has no solution, per se, gets the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likeliest culprit for your high latency is first and foremost the fact that you're using a wireless carrier's network, which are notorious for their high ping times.  Switching from one carrier to another probably wouldn't solve your problem, and even if you went from a 3G contract to 4G you probably wouldn't see that much of an improvement, especially as more and more people start buying 4G capable devices.

Additionally trying to do something as data-intensive as play World of Warcraft over your cell carrier's network is never going to feel right.  Games like that rely heavily on low response times and are best left for wired broadband connections.