# What causes latencies in the 1-10 second range?

Tags: tethering, 3g, 4g

I use my mobile phone as access point now and then. Both home and abroad I have regularly experienced extremely high latencies (10000ms) with fairly low packet loss (5%).

What causes this?

I have read [How can I reduce latency while tethering?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/how-can-i-reduce-latency-while-tethering) but that only answers what I already know: That it is due to wireless at the carrier.

So the question here is to get more details.

I never see the above behaviour in a wifi net (I will typically see loads of dropped packets, but a reasonable latency lower than 1000 ms), so something else is going on.
If I only get 5% loss, I imagine there is some store-and-forward going on: Where does that happen? Why can packets not be passed on for 10 seconds, but still not be lost?

If the carrier wanted to do something about it, what should they do?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is really a question for Android.SE (it's rather a general networking question). So if you don't get answers in a reasonable time, you might wish to flag your question to be migrated to the appropriate SE site (most likely [SU], but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: @Izzy How are you sure it is not limited to Android? I have only tested this on (several) Android phones. If you have seen the same behaviour on non-android phones, please share that information.

Comment: Ole, "I'm not sure" – as I wrote. It could well be implementations of the network stack specific to Android or a specific kernel (I'm no Android or Kernel developer, so I cannot say). I was just pointing out possibilities. But even if, the "issue as such" (i.e. what lies behind it) is rather network specific. Without knowing the underlying reason, it's hard to know where to look – and those are not Android specific ;) Note that I didn't mark your question off-topic, just giving some indicators.